# In GraphQL, if I'm trying to resolve the Address or a Person, how do I get the Address ID?

Tags: graphql, apollo

Consider this model:

```
type Address {
  id: ID!
}

type Person {
  id: ID!
  address: Address
}
```

I'm writing the resolver for `Person->address` to get the address of the person, which is in another DB table.

In order to do that, I need the `addressId` but I don't have it. The `addressId` property was available inside the `Person` resolver, but that was lost, since my GraphQL schema doesn't have an `addressId`.

How do I get the `addressId` inside the `Person.address` resolver?

##### PS:

One way I can do it, is to add an `addressId` to `Person`, but if I do that, I would have to add sibling IDs to all foreign keys in my GraphQL schema and this seems off. If that's the way to go, though, I'd do it

Answer (score 0):

The way I ended up solving this problem was to pair any child graph node with an ID property.

Example:

```
type Person {
 
  addressId: String
  address: Address

  occupationId:String
  ocupation: Ocupation

}
```

This way, my resolver function for `Person` would always resolve `addressId` and `occupationId` but the child resolvers would kick in for `address` and `occupation`. Inside these resolvers, `parent` would be `Person` and I would be able to read the `addressId` and `occupationId`.